# Change audio output

Tags: audio, triggers, bots

So I want to run multiple instances of a game, and be able to detect when one of the game makes a sound. To do so I want every game to be on a diffrent audio output. Cause I cant thinmk of any other way.

However CheVolume and IndieVolume does not work cause they cant seperate between instances of the same game, any clue what I can do?